# add map and markers in java desktop app

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, maps

I am trying to add an image in a java application as a map on top of which i need to place markers.
the markers should show when users check in at the marker's location. 
I have checked several open source tools and libraries such as geotool but none of them seemed to provide me with the needed options. (Geotool does not allow me to add markers or integrate the map in another frame), instead it opens the map in a new window every time.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A JPanel which does its own paintingComponent. ImageIO.read for reading images, gc.drawImage and you are almost done. (As you sought, and did not find convincing stuff.)

Comment: thanks for the reply, i finally used a jpg image as a background, and added labels with pin imageIcons as markers.